# Issue with a space character slipping into a string

Tags: vb6

I am building a lengthy string in vb6 to store my insert statement. While adding column names my string looks like this:

```
SQLinsert = "INSERT INTO tableName (columnOne, columnTwo"
```

I am then adding columnThree name with the following statement:

```
SQLinsert = SQLinsert & ", columnThree"
```

The resulting string I get is:

```
SQLinsert = "INSERT INTO tableName (columnOne, columnTwo, colum
nThree"
```

There seems to be a space between "colum" and "nThree". Also it looks like I am getting a line break. Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: I never saw something like this, are you sure there is no symbol or unicode char between "colum" and "nThree"?

Comment: The code you have will not insert a new line so the issue is where/how you are viewing the string or something that is happens to it after you concatenate.

Comment: Not sure what the *issue itself* is, but you can try to remove the line breaks with `Replace(Replace(Replace(__yourString__, vbCrLf, ""), vbCr, ""), vbLf, "")`

Comment: I know older VT terminals - when you copy a line it will automatically add a `vbCrLf` to the end of that line. I only bring this up since you are still using VB6.

Comment: I am sure there is no characters between "colum" and "nThree". Before the statement is executed, there are just more columns and values being added to the string.

I view the string using Immediate window in Visual Basic 6.0. When I copy the final string (insert statement) as it is and try to execute it manually, I get the following error:
"Incorrect syntax near 'nThree'."

Comment: The VB6 immediate window has a character line limit of 1023 characters, a longer string displayed to the immediate window will be broken into separate lines.  If you then copy-paste that resulting displayed text, you will end up with CR-LF characters in the middle of your string. From your comment, it's not clear if this is occurring with your runtime code, or only when you "copy the final string ... and try to execute it manually ...".